# what is the steps to create ArrayLlist on android(client) to retrieve information from Mysql(server)?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to create an array-list to retrieve 20 people information from MySql on My server.

So, I declare class and put the attribute on it, and create object from this class.

Also I declare array-list and put loop to create object each time.
Moreover I put class for parcel (I dont know why should do this step but I found all the internet web doing that)

So, can anyone explain to me why we should use parcel?
And what should i do to complete my code to let my application retrieve information about people from Mysql in server?

please please i hope i get replay from anyone to answer my Question!
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Parcelable interface if you want to send objects of your class between processes. Binder (Android mechanism for IPC) knows only about simple types (int, boolean, String, and so on) and, thus, can transfer them between processes. It does not know how to parse an object of your class. To explain Binder how to do this you implement Parcelable interface.